# CDN + SSL + CUSTOM DOMAIN - what's the best way?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, rackspace-cloud

I need cloud storage, that CNAMES to my custom domain, that I can still set up with SSL.

Cloudfront does it but the price is $600/month (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/) which is ludicrous.

Anyone have any experience with this and can direct to the most cost effective option?

Only complication is my app is on Heroku and I'm already doing SSL for my custom domain through there. So this would be for a sub-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CLoudfront with SNI SSL at no extra charge: 
http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/05/amazon-cloudront-announces-sni-custom-ssl/

Comment: Got it. Is that the best option? I'm just worried about compatibility. Apparently SNI SSL doesn't work with Windows XP + *any* version of IE.

Comment: I have used https://sni.velox.ch/ to test lots of clients and, as far as i could test, SNI support is pretty extensive nowadays. But we do not support IE 6.. other than that, you should be fine. Check the list on the bottom of that page.

Comment: "Apparently SNI SSL doesn't work with Windows XP" - correct. Its a limitation in Windows's `SChannel`. You need Vista and above (and it looks like Windows XP still holds 27.69% of market share. See [Desktop Operating System Market Share](http://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0)).